# Different Configurations for different "Build Variants"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have four different build variants. However I find it irritating that I need to go to Project > Build Variant each time I need to build another variant. Is it possible to link a Configuration directly to a build variant? Similar to how XCode can be used to build different version of an app using "Schemes".

From the Configuration settings there are only a link to the module and not the modules build varaint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with XCode but you can easily change the variant you are building from "Build Variants". This can be opened in 1 click from the bottom left corner of the IDE, see attached image. If it doesn't show there for you clicking the icon at the bottom left will provide it.

[image: Build Variants]

Alternatively, you can set a shortcut for the view by going to File->Settings->Keymap and search for "Build Variants". This path is ok for Windows and Linux OSes but slightly different on Mac OS X which I believe you are using.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I do it now. But would have preferred to change it with configuration. I already have two: one for build and run, and the other one for building all build variants. It feel like it should be possible to add one configuration for each build variant.